# How does pytorch broadcasting work?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, pytorch, array-broadcasting

```
torch.add(torch.ones(4,1), torch.randn(4))
```

produces a Tensor with size: `torch.Size([4,4])`.

Can someone provide a logic behind this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[PyTorch *`broadcasting`*](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) is based on *numpy broadcasting* semantics which can be understood by reading [**`numpy broadcasting rules`**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) or *[PyTorch broadcasting guide](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics)*. Expounding the concept with an example would be intuitive to understand it better. So, please see the example below:

```
In [27]: t_rand
Out[27]: tensor([ 0.23451,  0.34562,  0.45673])

In [28]: t_ones
Out[28]: 
tensor([[ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.],
        [ 1.]])
```

Now for [**`torch.add(t_rand, t_ones)`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.add), visualize it like:

```
               # shape of (3,)
               tensor([ 0.23451,      0.34562,       0.45673])
      # (4, 1)          | | | |       | | | |        | | | |
      tensor([[ 1.],____+ | | |   ____+ | | |    ____+ | | |
              [ 1.],______+ | |   ______+ | |    ______+ | |
              [ 1.],________+ |   ________+ |    ________+ |
              [ 1.]])_________+   __________+    __________+
```

which should give the output with tensor of shape `(4,3)` as:

```
# shape of (4,3)
In [33]: torch.add(t_rand, t_ones)
Out[33]: 
tensor([[ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673]])
```

---

Also, note that we get exactly the same result even if we pass the arguments in a reverse order as compared to the previous one:

```
# shape of (4, 3)
In [34]: torch.add(t_ones, t_rand)
Out[34]: 
tensor([[ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673],
        [ 1.23451,  1.34562,  1.45673]])
```

Anyway, I prefer the former way of understanding for more straightforward intuitiveness.

---

For pictorial understanding, I culled out more examples which are enumerated below:

**`Example-1:`**

[image: broadcasting-1]

---

**`Example-2:`**:

[image: theano broadcasting]

`T` and `F` stand for `True` and `False` respectively and indicate along which dimensions we allow broadcasting (source: [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/broadcasting.html)).

---

**`Example-3:`**

Here are some shapes where the array `b` is  *broadcasted* appropriately to *attempt* to match the shape of the array `a`.

[image: broadcastable shapes]

As shown above, the broadcasted `b` may still not match the shape of `a`, and so the operation `a + b` will fail whenever the final broadcasted shapes do not match.

Comment: great answer, and example, especially the pictorial examples

Answer (score 11):

### Example for `a + b`

Let:

```
a.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1)
b.shape = (      4, 1, 6, 7, 8)
```

**Step 1:** `b` will be padded on the **left** (*only* the left!) until both  have the same number of axes:

```
a.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1)
b.shape = (1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8)    <-- padded left with 1s
```

**Step 2:** Next, if an axis of `b` has length `1`, that axis will be repeated until its length matches the corresponding axis of `a`:

```
a.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1)
b.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)    <-- changed 1s to match a
```

**Step 3:** Next, if an axis of `a` has length `1`, that axis will be repeated until its length matches the corresponding axis of `b`:

```
a.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)    <-- changed 1s to match b
b.shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

These shapes match, so `a + b` will run successfully. (If they had not matched, `a + b` would fail.)

Comment: This answer is much better than the most voted one since it clearly shows the routine of how we get the final result.